# Putting labels inside text inputs - not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on an online enrolment form for a training organisation. The labels for the text input boxes have been placed inside the inputs themselves using the solution at http://attardi.org/labels/

It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and IE8, but for some reason in IE7 there's a problem coming up (surprise, surprise!)

If I click on the input field in the area where the label is, the browser does not focus on the input. The input field will only go live if I click on the white space after the label, or bizarrely, if I click slightly below the input field.

Is this a CSS or a JavaScript issue, and can anyone suggest a solution?

You can access the form in it's entirety at http://testing.xenongroupadmin.com/enrolment but beware - the HTML, CSS and HTML files are very hefty and could take some time to sift through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the script you've linked to.

Use regular html5 `placeholder` attribute (http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) - it's the cleanest solution to get what you need in most browsers. To handle IE7/8 you can use javascript shiv, like this one: http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.com/2012/02/html5-placeholder-in-ie7-and-ie8-fixed.html